# Why this batch marker don't work?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file to open only one of two different files, which are:

- TeamViewerQS_**de**.exe
- TeamViewerQS_**en**.exe

If the customers have installed the `*_en.exe`, I need to start that `.exe` file:

```
start C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe
if not exist C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe goto :EN

:EN
start C:\TeamViewerQS_en.exe
```

I get the error that Windows can't find TeamViewerQS_**en**.exe, despiste the _**de**.exe version exists on my PC.
Is there a better way to differentiate the file name in batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe
IF not exist C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe goto :EN
:: goto :eof also can be used instead of exit
exit /b 0
:EN
start C:\TeamViewerQS_en.exe
```

You need exit clause the labels (lines starting with `:`) are ignored and `start C:\TeamViewerQS_en.exe` will be executed.

You can also do this:

```
start C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe 2>nul || start C:\TeamViewerQS_en.exe
```

[link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)

Comment: thank you - i unterstand it now

worked also with start C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe
IF not exist C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe else C:\TeamViewerQS_en.exe like rudicangiotti writed.

Comment: @user3675536  it will be better like that: `if exist "C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe" start "C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe" else start "C:\TeamViewerQS_en.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, if the `TeamViewerQS_de.exe` version exists, there is not a condition that bypasses the statement that makes running the `TeamViewerQS_en.exe` version. Then, you can just add a `else` block to the `if not exist` condition to jump over the statement that starts the english version.
Here is a working script, with an edit that consists in a conditional branch before the starting block and other `goto` statements:

```
if exist C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe goto :DE else goto :EN  

:DE  
start C:\TeamViewerQS_de.exe
goto :EOF  
:EN  
start C:\TeamViewerQS_en.exe  
:EOF  
echo Task accomplished  
pause
```

In this way the `ERRORLEVEL` should stay for all the task at 0 level; this can be useful if this script is enclosed in another one that makes also other operations liked to that variable.